# Delay switching uiviews

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

when i press on UIBUTTON to switch from one uiview to the next, the button stays pressed - probably beacuse the next uiview is loading (there is a JSON array that should be load) and just after few seconds the uiview is switching.
how can i force it to first switch uiview and just than to load whatever there is?

Answer (score 0):

U can put the "loading data" logic inside the - (void)viewDidLoad of the second view controller or u can do the loading in a separate thread and them go back to the main thread passing the data to the other view controller. One thing is clear, if your button stays pressed, you blocking the main thread and that is bad.